# Dynamic Nested Namespace Routing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested

i was doing this with my **routes.rb**

```
namespace :main do
    get "/" => 'sites#index'
    get "/:action" => 'sites#:action'
    
    namespace :dashboard do
        get '/' => 'dashboards#index'
        resources :masters
    end
  end
```

all results was success with static :main namespace

> localhost/main/index
>
> localhost/main/dashboard/:action

but i want to make main routed **dynamically** with reading params[:master_url], like

> localhost/**blog1**/dashboard/:action
>
> localhost/**blog2**/dashboard/:action

i was trying adding code below based [on this tuts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes)

```
get ':master_url/:controller(/:action(/:id))', controller: /main\/[^\/]+/
```

but failed when access

> localhost/url1/index

any help are apreciated thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide the path argument to namespace:

```
namespace :main, path: ':master_url'
```

[reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping/namespace)

Comment: great worked ! but just for dynamic routing for main namespace, but it breaks the dashboard path, it say action dashboard not exist :/ .

Comment: It will generate the route `/:master_url/:action` that'll be processed by `sites#:action`. Isn't it?

Comment: allright got it, i think it was a routing probs. but for this topic it was solved enough. thanks a lot @Rodrigo ;)